# Can I regain hearts?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

When you take damage you lose hearts (just like in the traditional Minecraft game).  Will my hearts replenish, and if so how does this occur?

Comment: Before blindly answering please actually read the question and tags. This question is about *Telltale Games' Minecraft Story Mode*. Not Minecraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesse has a separate health bar for each fight. No matter how much damage you take (as long as you don't actually die), you will start the next fight with full health.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no regeneration or hunger mechanic** in Minecraft Story Mode.
The fight determines player wins or dies regardless the health left after the fight. If you die you have a option to continue from last save.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of regenerating health when it comes to battles and going underwater. For each fight, you get spare health. You don't have hunger either, which is lucky for you. If you die, you reload back to a previous save.